# What do the Speed0x controls do in SpeedFan?

Tags: cpu, temperature, cooling, speedfan

I'm monitoring my PC for suspected overheating, and I want to know what the Speed01, Speed02, 
and Speed03 controls do in SpeedFan? Specifically what does the Speed03 set to 41 mean?

My CPU is an old Pentium 4, 2.8GHz single core. Does my system temperature look okay?

[image]

Comment: Basically, don't worry about CPU temps unless it's idling at over 60C or gets above 70-80C depending on the processor.  (with the exclusion of the amazing P3s that could run without a heatsink and survive 85C)

Comment: @earkz: What P3s could run without a heatsink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the different fans in your system. Some fans have RPM controls, others do not. If they do, their speed can usually be controlled here.

Your CPU temp looks fine. Prescotts throttle around 75C, I don't remember Northwoods off hand, but they should be similar. 40C is normal.